# How to pass parameter between states not in a url?

Tags: angular

I am wondering how can I pass parameters, that won't be visible in URL?

As of now I have:

```
{path: '/editUser/:userId', name: 'Edit User', component: UserEditComponent}
```

And when I navigate to this view like that:

```
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['Edit User',{userId: id}]"
```

The `userId` will show up in the URL.

How can I set it, so that it is not visible in the URL?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just change it to some unreadable form?

Comment: Practically i could do that - but I am wondering if there is an option of not displaying it at all :)

Comment: Even I wonder with it :-)

Comment: There is a 'data' property of RouteConfig, but I cannot find any other info about in documentation..

Comment: You can think of shared service with single instance shared among components.

Answer (score 5):

Good Question !

I don't know exactly how to do that but yes I know alternate of same so posting as answer may to help someone.

Basically There are two options (up to my knowledge) to send data via routing

- RouteParams (as used in question)
- data (property at the time of routing)

## RouteParams

Now when we send data using `RouteParams` we have to define in the similer way like this:

```
{path: '/editUser/:userId', name: 'Edit User', component: UserEditComponent}

<a href="#" [routerLink]="['Edit User',{userId: id}]"
```

By using this method we send data normaly but all data is visible in the URL

## Data

when we don't want to show data in the URL path than we have to send data via routing using `data` property of the `@RouteConfig annotation` provided by angualr2. by using this property we can send additional data to the components at the time of the route configuration without showing it in the URL. here is example of this property.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/product/:id', component: ProductDetailComponentParam,
     as: 'ProductDetail', data: {isProd: true}}])

export class ProductDetailComponentParam {
    productID: string;
    constructor(params: RouteParams, data: RouteData) {
        this.productID = params.get('id');
 
        console.log('Is this prod environment', data.get('isProd'));
    }
}
```

by using this we can send data via routing without showing in the URL.
working example of same:
[http://plnkr.co/edit/N5IzUH0pc3nN1O7iQZkD?p=preview]](http://plnkr.co/edit/N5IzUH0pc3nN1O7iQZkD?p=preview%5D)

for more info read out this [awesome article](https://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/)

Comment: Could you show me example wehre I can dynamically set data, that I want to pass to a route?

Comment: `RouteData` is not intended to be used for passing dynamic data to the route. Use `RouteParams` for this.

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9757#issuecomment-229847781 for using Data in RC.4 router