# Angular 2 add id to the HTML tag from a component

Tags: dom, angular, updates

Hi I have an login component, which is something like front page. The problem is that there is a shared header and when I m on the login page the header is a bit smaller than the other pages. And this is controlled by an id attr in `<html>` tag. So is it possible when I load this login component to add that id to `<html>` my Login component is looking like this now.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: "./layout/login/login.component.html"
})
export class LoginComponent{ }
```

Comment: could you please explain bit more what you exactly want to do ? `id` means ? some parameter while loading `login component` ?

Comment: Hi there, I would like to update <html id="main"> to <html id="login"> when `@Routes([
  {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '*', component: LoginComponent}
])` but no Idea where I have to do it. I have just started to learn angular2 and there are too many new stuff. In angular 1 I probably would use jquery when the router is resolved but in angular2 no Idea, which is the right way

Comment: simple you can pass parameter(your id) along with routing and get that parameter in the constructor of login component and set `id` dynamically of your html view.

Comment: Read out this answer surely help in your case http://stackoverflow.com/a/36030932/5043867

Comment: ty man, just at the end I still have to use jquery to add id to the <html> in the constructor of my login component right? I m asking because I saw something like `BrowserDomAdapter` but I when I try to load it form `@angular2/platform/browser` the editor saying that the module is not there

Comment: no i dont think you have to use JQuery for such task, you can simply get by attribute binding of angular2.

Comment: Attribute binding can't be used outside the root component and Angular can't be used on the `<html>` tag. I still don't understand why you need the `id` on the `<html>` element.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you are right, the problem is that I m using already built admin template, and this template has this `id` to specify that the header and some other staff, with different dimensions, backgrounds ect. So I don't want to re-built the all stylesheet to change that. It's quite big :). And I was thinking if is possible to do it with angular. Now I m using jQuery and it's working, but I don't really like the way, have to replicate that part in each component, so I was thinking to extend the Router somehow :), but still don't know and do the jQuery logic there

Comment: You can subsribe to the router in the root component and do the updating (jQuery) for all paths from there.

Comment: ty very much for this suggestion can you provide me, some short example or link where I can get an example of this subscription. It would be great. thank you in advance!